# AngularJS directive move checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive

If I have two or more checkboxes how would I move unchecked checkboxes below the ones that are checked. At the moment I have simple HTML below, so if Checkbox 2 is checked it should move to the top and Checkbox 1 should move down.

The 2 ways I have thought of doing this is:

1. create and array on the scope and use ng-repeat to populate the checkboxes then apply a filter based on weather or not a checkbox is checked or splice the array. Only problem with this is I don't really want to define my checkboxes on the scope.
2. create a directive to somehow manipulate the dom element.

If someone has had a similar problem what would you recommend to be the best solution?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    Please check one or more boxes <i tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="On the Bottom!" class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
    <span ng-show="checked || checked_2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>
    <span ng-hide="checked || checked_2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input ng-model="checked" type="checkbox" value="1">
            Checkbox 1
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
             <input ng-model="checked_2" type="checkbox" value="2">
             Checkbox 2
        </label>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="checked || checked_2" class="text-danger">Some error message!</div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter:

JS

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.users = [
      { Name: 'John', Selected: false },
      { Name: 'Mary', Selected: false },
      { Name: 'Jane', Selected: false },
      { Name: 'Tom', Selected: false },
      { Name: 'Benny', Selected: false }
   ];
});
```

HTML

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller='Ctrl'> 
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy: ['-Selected','Name']">
            {{user.Name }} <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.Selected" />
          </li>
      </ul>
 </body>
```

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DDx6yfoMeP7Z588Opro3?p=preview)